# JPG file is more grey than file in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg

Hi I'm new to this forum and I have a question. I am a fashion design student and at the moment I am retouching some pictures from a photoshoot. I like the colors I have in Photoshop but when I save it as a JPG somehow it all turns a little flat and grey, instead of the lively colors it is supposed to have. I have made a screenshot of both pictures, you can see it here: [image]

Photoshop is set to RGB mode and I am saving it as the highest quality JPG. I really hope someone knows why this could happen, because unfortunately Google hasn't given me any answers. Thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 2):

The exported file needs to be converted to sRGB either before exporting or during the export if you are using "Save for Web" option. If you are using that option you will see Convert to sRGB with a check box next to it, put a check mark there and then save it. If you are simply saving it as JPEG, then before saving it:

1. Go to Edit/Convert to Profile
2. Choose for the destination profile sRGB
3. Click OK

You will not see anything noticeable in Photoshop but when you save the image it will have the right color space for viewing anywhere. By the way, if you normally work in 16-bit mode, you should also convert it to 8-bit before converting the profile